# How can i trigger and inject the value to the router function

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkitspeechrecognition, routerjs

I have the following issue I poll a file for words, when found, I want to trigger a match using the trigger function and direct a match to the molly map function, currently the script trigger from voice using the webKitSpeechRecon.

```
// inject fun into trigger
function callmic(){
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100001)
jQuery.get("https://localhost/newfile.txt?" + randomnumber, function(callingmic) {
    console.log(callingmic);
    console.log("Mobile App");
// route to molly
});
}
```

here is the full script

```
var getSpeech = (function () {
if (window.location.protocol != "https:")
 window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
    if (typeof webkitSpeechRecognition === "undefined") return null;

    var escapeRegExp  = /[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g,
        optionalParam = /\((.*?)\)/g,
        namedParam    = /(\(\?)?:\w+/g,
        splatParam    = /\*\w+/g,
        convertFormatToRegExp = function (format) {
            format = format
                .replace(escapeRegExp, "\\$&")
                .replace(optionalParam, "(?:$1)?")
                .replace(namedParam, function (match, optional) {
                    return optional ? match : "(\\w+)";
                })
                .replace(splatParam, "(.*?)");
            return new RegExp("^" + format + "$", "i");
        },
        trigger = function (transcript) {
            console.log(transcript);
            for (var i = 0; i < molly.length; i++) {
                var result = molly[i].regex.exec(transcript);
                if (result && result.length) {
                    result.splice(0, 1);
                    molly[i].callback.apply(molly[i].context, result);
                }
            }
        };

    var speechRecognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition(),
        molly = [],
        recognizing = false;
    speechRecognition.continuous = true;
    speechRecognition.lang = "en-GB";

    speechRecognition.onerror = function (event) {
    speechRecognition.start();
    $('#micset').attr('src', 'fade.png');
        }
    speechRecognition.onend = function (event) {
    speechRecognition.start();
    $('#micset').attr('src', 'fade.png');
        }
    $('#send').click( function() {
            speechRecognition.start();
        });

    speechRecognition.onresult = function (event) {
        var finalTranscript = ""; //, interimTranscript = "";
        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
                finalTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
    $('#micset').attr('src', 'fade.png');
        trigger(finalTranscript.trim()); // + interimTranscript);
    };

    function getSpeech(properties) {
    $('#micset').attr('src', 'chromemicred.png');
        if (!properties) return;

        for (var property in properties) {
            this[property] = properties[property];
        }
        this.route(properties["molly"]);
    }

    getSpeech.prototype = {
        route: function (format, callback) {
            if (typeof format === "object") {
                var mollyObj = format;
                for (var format in mollyObj) {
                    this.route(format, mollyObj[format]);
                }
            } else {
                molly.push({
                    regex: convertFormatToRegExp(format),
                    callback: this[callback] || callback,
                    context: this
                });
            }
        },
        // insert new trigger here from ape refresh every 2read

        trigger: function (transcript) {
            trigger(transcript);
        },

        start: function () {
            if (!recognizing) {
                recognizing = true;
                speechRecognition.start();

            }
        },

        stop: function () {
            if (recognizing) {
                recognizing = false;
                speechRecognition.start();
            }
        }
    };

    return getSpeech;
})();
var mapp = new getSpeech({
                molly: {
                    "help": "help",
                    "go to youtube": "youtube",
                    "say hello to :name": "sayHello",
                    "find *query on :engine": "find",
                    "question *words": "quests",
                    "search *wordsearch": "fluidsearch",
                    "define *lookup": "define",
                                   "hello": "hello",
                                   "tell me a joke" : "joke",
                                   "joke" : "joke",
                                   "search" : "search",
                                   "add :item to my shopping list" : "trolley",
                    ":item to my shopping list" : "trolley",
                    ":item on shopping list" : "trolley",
                                   "put :item to my shopping list" : "trolley",
                    "switch light on" : "pwron",
                    "lights on" : "pwron",
                    "light on" : "pwron",
                    "test" : "callin",
                    "show me text messages" : "sms",
                    "call alerts" : "callin",
                    "lights off" : "pwro",
                    "light off" : "pwro",
                    "switch off light" : "pwro",
                    "switch off the light" : "pwro",
                    "switch light off" : "pwro",
                    "what time is it" : "time",
                    "question" : "q",
                    "time" : "time",
                    "spell *mollyword" : "spell",
                    "play radio *station" : "one",
                    "radio *station" : "one",
                    "play music by *artist" : "music",
                    "find me pictures of *image" : "images",
                    "set timer *inmins" : "timer",
                    "set timer for *inmins" : "timer"
                },          
                help: function () {
                    window.location.href = "help.php";
                },
                           search: function () {
                           $('body').load('altx.php');
                           },
                q: function () {
                var quest = new Audio('/spk/knowjumpinnen.mp3');
                quest.play();
                           $('body').load('altq.php');
                           },
                           hello: function () {
                var hi = new Audio('/spk/hitheregen.mp3');
                            hi.play();
                },
                trolley: function (item) {
                //send trolley to supermarket and store in users crandle++
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "https://xxx/spk/gu.php?filename=item" + item + "&sw=sw=1&txt=" + item + " is now on the shopping list",
                success: function(resp) {
                console.log("shopping list update");
                var trolley= new Audio("/spk/item" + item + "en.mp3");
                trolley.play();
                $('#notificationsBody').html('<a id=\'listitems\' href=\'/\'>View shopping list</a>');
                },
                error: function() {
                console.log("shopping list error");
                }
                });
                },
                time: function () {
                var timelook= new Audio('/spk/lookingupresen.mp3');
                timelook.play();
                window.location.href = "i.php?a=web&m=1&oq=1&sw=sw%3D1&q=time"; 
                },
                pwro: function () {

                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'xxx',
                success: function(resp) {
                console.log("im hitting the power function");
                $( "div.off" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
                },
                error: function() {
                $( "div.failure" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
                }
                });
                },
                pwron: function () {
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'xxx',
                success: function(resp) {
                $( "div.on" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
                },
                error: function() {
                $( "div.failure" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
                }
                });
                },
                spell: function (mollyword) {
                $('body').load("xxx" + mollyword + "&mp3=1");
                },
                music: function (artist) {
                window.location.href = "xxx?search_query=" + artist + "&askquickly=1";
                },

joke: function () {
var jokeArray = ["/spk/ajokeen.mp3", "/spk/ajokenameen.mp3", "/spk/ajokespaceen.mp3", "/spk/ajokeanten.mp3"];
var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * jokeArray.length);
var aajoke = jokeArray[choice];
var ajoke = new Audio(aajoke);
var coins = new Audio('/spk/flipcoindsen.mp3');
ajoke.play();
},
                sayHello: function (name) {
                    alert("Hi, " + (name || "there") + "!");
                },

                define: function (lookup) {
                var defineaudio= new Audio("/spk/" + lookup + "en.mp3");
                defineaudio.play();
                },

                one: function (station) {
                           var prestation= new Audio("//xxx" + station + "en.mp3");
                prestation.play();
                $('#instructions').html('<div id=\'stations\'><br><br><br><br><img id=\'testimgstation\' src=\'/images/bbc' + station + '.png\' /><a id=\'teststationmute\' href=\'/\'><img id=\'mute\' src=\'/images/mute.png\'></a></div>');
                var oneradio= new Audio("xxx");
                oneradio.play();
                },

                sms: function () {
                smsload();
                setInterval(function(){
                    smsload()
                }, 20000);
                },
                callin: function () {
                callload();
                setInterval(function(){
                    callload()
                }, 10000);
                },
                quests: function (words) {
                window.open("xxx?sw=sw=1&a=web&m=1&q=" + words);
                },

                timer: function (inmins) {
                    window.location.href = "xxx" + inmins;
                },

                fluidsearch: function (wordsearch) {
                    window.open("xxx?a=web&sw=sw=1&m=1&q=" + wordsearch);
                },
                images: function (image) {
                    window.open("https://askquickly.org/i.php?a=images&sw=sw=1&m=1&q=" + image);
                },

                find: function (query, engine) {
                    window.open("xxx);
                }
            });

            mapp.start();

            function smsrefreshload(){
    $('#notificationTitle').load('xxx',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}
function smsload(){
    $('#notificationsBody').load('xxx');
$('#notificationTitle').html('Text messages');
$('#notificationFooter').html('Speak');
$('#notificationAu').html('<span id="notification_count">SMS</span>');
    } 

function callrefreshload(){
    $('#notificationTitle').load('xxx?demoauth=1',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}
function callload(){
    $('#notificationsBody').load('callin.php?demoauth=1');
$('#notificationFooter').html('Speak');
$('#notificationTitle').html('Incoming calls');
$('#notificationAu').html('<span id="notification_count">Calls</span>');
    }

setInterval(function(){
    callmic()
}, 5000);

// inject fun in trigger
function callmic(){
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100001)
jQuery.get("http://localhost/newfile.txt?" + randomnumber, function(callingmic) {
    console.log(callingmic);
    console.log("Mobile App");
// route to molly for action
});
}
```

Comment: I would like to use both the voice and the content of the file to route to a action named var mapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to bypass the webspeech and inject manually

mapp.trigger(callingmic);